# Using PHP read word in textarea line by line and insert to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, textarea, readline

1. I need to read data which inserted via textarea line by line
2. Then need to search for certain words (Eg Fruits)
3. Once its found that word, form next line onward insert to DB line by line until it finds a new blank line (Apple   Mango   Orange)

[image: sample screen attached]

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  But if you must, just explode the input text on newline

Comment: Comment#2 has a point.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can code like:

$val = 'Veg
Tomato
Potato

Fruits
mango
banana';
$textAreaVal = $val;
$arrVal = explode(PHP_EOL, $textAreaVal);
for($i=0; $i < count($arrVal); $i++){
    $type = '';
    $isInIf = false;
    if($arrVal[i] == 'Veg'){
        $type = 'Veg';
    }else if($arrVal[i] == 'Fruits'){
        $type = 'Fruits';
    }

    if($type != ''){
        // your insert query here
        // insert into tbl(type, name) values('$type', '$arrVal[i]')
    }
}
```

Comment: may I know the reason of -1 ?

Comment: @Gabriel's Messanger- I dint asked you to write software, give some sample/suggestion like Rahul